# snap-confine refuses to launch application to avoid permission attack

Tags: package-management, software-installation, snap

I just installed a program with the package manager snap.

I installed the app with the following:

`sudo snap install cloudcompare`

I logged out and logged back in my machine to refresh the path. The program is still not launching while icons and path exist now. Here is how I launch the program from the terminal:

`cloudcompare.CloudCompare`

which returns:

`snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`

Do you have any idea how to prevent this refusing to continue?

Comment: What version of snap packages do you have installed? I have the following and it works.
```$ snap version
snap       2.23
snapd      2.23
series     16
linuxmint  18.1
kernel     4.4.0-53-generic```

Comment: `snap --version
snap       2.22.7
snapd      2.22.7
series     16
linuxmint  18.1
kernel     4.4.0-53-generic
` I have reinstalled snapd, and the application cloud compare. I now obtain a different error: `cloudcompare.CloudCompare 
cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory
` The application developper are mentioning that it might be related to snap and mint. http://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2333&p=9181&sid=0f0b02e4d94c4c498e0510b1689912a8#p9181

Comment: Like I said, I tested on Mint 18.1, so not sure what is wrong there. This could be a bug in snapd. I'd be inclined to file it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bugs

Comment: created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1732409

Comment: The exact same thing happens on plain Ubuntu 18.04 - see related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074114/snap-refuses-to-launch-applications

Comment: This error was symptomatic of an apparmor issue for me.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1074243/347835

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine && sudo apt install -y snapd
```

has fixed the problem for me

Comment: @leaf4good Thanks for the answer. Following your recomendation, I now have installed snap version 2.22.6 and snapd 2.22.6. and cannot even install a version of the desired package as I get this error:

Comment: <error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "core" (1577) security profiles (skipping security profiles setup for snap "cloudcompare" when handling snap "core": no state entry for key)
- Setup snap "core" (1577) security profiles (cannot setup apparmor for snap "core": cannot unload apparmor profile "snap.core.hook.configure": cannot unload apparmor profile: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?>

Comment: The apparmor package is up to date, so I am quite confused on what is happening. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this "fixes" the problem, but in my case I also had to reinstall my application. Surely there's an easier way, or does snap mean we have to reinstall apps every so often?!