# snap refuses to launch applications

Tags: snap

I’ve installed vscode and vlc via snap commands and each time I launch them from the terminal, I got this message:

> snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should
>   be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks

Any help please!

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Possible solution:  https://askubuntu.com/a/906630/231142

Comment: ...another possible solution: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be/4994 There are quite a few links, if you search.

Answer (score 7):

These steps help me resolve permanently my problem:

- Remove snapd: **sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine**
- Update: **sudo apt update**
- Reinstall it: **sudo apt install snapd**
- Check apparmor's status: **systemctl status apparmor**
- If status inactive, then activate it: **systemctl start apparmor**
- **Now install any app you want via snap commands line**

Remember, you must **check** and **activate** **apparmor** before **installing** any **app**.

Comment: It shall be good thing if someone can show us how to activate permanently apparmor

Answer (score 3):

The other answers make us uninstall the snap that subsequently removes all the apps installed via snap.
This can be a problem if there are many apps installed via snap (as in my case).
Easier fix is to check the status of apparmor via

> sudo systemctl status apparmor

and then restart the service via

> sudo systemctl restart apparmor

Answer (score 0):

After following the instructions in [Goodness's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074243/89097) I needed to reinstall my snap apps. Obviously I don't want to do that repeatedly.

The main snap app I use is [PyCharm](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and I found some advice about [using the classic option](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/01/09/how-to-snap-introducing-classic-confinement) when installing to a more relaxed policy. For example:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

It remains to be seen whether that solves the problem permanently.

The reason this has happened is due to [this bug in snapd](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1732409).

Comment: Just to make it a bit more explicit: If apparmor is not running , start it. (see Goodness' answer). Then install the app of your choice with the classic mode. No need to reinstall snap. At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of this problem was that the apparmor service was *disabled* (i.e., it wasn't launching on boot). Starting apparmor (with `sudo systemctl restart apparmor`, as described in other answers) *temporarily* fixed the problem. But, it would return each time I rebooted.

To enable apparmor permanently, do:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now apparmor
```

(I would have just left this as a comment on https://askubuntu.com/a/1179347/878477 but I don't have enough reputation to do so.)