# Applications don't start anymore after upgrade (Vs Code, Discord, Riot etc)

Tags: upgrade

so after an upgrade I have the following apps which don't start anymore:

VS Code
Dicord
Riot
Tusk

potentially others. Slack is still working.

I have tried reinstalling VS Code, the new version starts for ~5 seconds and then it dies.
I have also changed the permission of the VS Code config directory to make sure my user has permissions to it as I found googling and still doesn't fix the issue. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2

thanks.

Comment: Does your /var/log/syslog say anything about these crashes?

Comment: please start `code` (? or `vscode`) from terminal and see if there is any error output.

Comment: in /var/log/syslog/ I see something like : Feb 12 13:13:17 adrian-XPS-15-9570 discord_discord.desktop[7808]: snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by reinstalling snapd & all the affected apps.

thank you.

this helped:
[snap refuses to launch applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074114/snap-refuses-to-launch-applications)

ps:  after a while I had the same issue.

I also checked apparmour (it was dead) and I restarted it.

sudo systemctl status apparmor
sudo systemctl restart apparmor

now seems to be working again, let's see for how long.