# Visual Studio Code doesn't start anymore

Tags: 18.04, software-center, visual-studio-code

I'm completely new to Linux and wanted to experiment a little, so I don't really know what I'm doing. I am on working  Ubuntu 18.04 and I have been unable to get Visual Studio Code to start again, even though it was working before. Trying to launch it through the application menu only resulted in a short loading animation followed by nothing. Launching it through the terminal issued `/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object`. 
I already tried to reinstall it. But attempting it through the terminal somehow didn't work at all 
`manuel@Manuel-Ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --remove visual-studio-code
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove visual-studio-code which isn't installed`. According to the Ubuntu Software center it was installed.

I tried the suggestion by @karel [snap-confine refuses to launch application to avoid permission attack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888497/snap-confine-refuses-to-launch-application-to-avoid-permission-attack), which didn't help my problem.

Comment: Why don't you try to remove the same from software centre?

Comment: I did. But my goal is not to remove it. ;)

Comment: Did you install it using snap or deb package? I sometimes have problems launching programs installed in snap

Answer (score 0):

[snap-confine refuses to launch application to avoid permission attack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888497/snap-confine-refuses-to-launch-application-to-avoid-permission-attack) only accomplished that I can't see Visual Studio Code in the Software Center at all. However I finally managed to install Visual Studio Code by following the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux). It seems like everything is working again now.